# How to get post and add post nav link for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently, I make a custom page using PHP in Wordpress. I tried to get all the post filtered by specific tag. Here is my PHP code for get the post and insert it into the div:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row box">
            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tag' => 'artikelseriesomb2020',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'paged' => $paged,
            );
            $arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :

                while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :
                    $arr_posts->the_post();
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($arr_post->ID), 'large');
            ?>
                    <div class="col-mt-4" style="padding:10px;">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img class="card-img-top" data-no-lazy="1" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">BACA SELENGKAPNYA</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to display 10 post per page and display a nav link in the bottom of the template so user can click to another page to see another/the rest of the posts. I tried this single code:

```
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

But it doesn't display any nav link. Is there something wrong with my code? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it may help you!
put it inside IF and after endwhile.

```
echo '<div class="post_pagination">';
$total_pages = $arr_posts->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
    ));
}
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for contributing but please note that code-only answers are discouraged because they don't explain how it solves the problem. If you edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, it would be more useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues in future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It's quite easy!

First, I use this function to generate the pagination:

```
<?php
function pagination_bar()
{
    global $my_query;

    $total_pages = $my_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1) {
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

Then I call the function:

```
<?php
        if (have_posts()) :
            pagination_bar();
        endif;
        ?>
```

That's it.